# How to convert PDB XML read to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have an XML set of data named `pdb_params` like this:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no' ?>\n<dataset>\n  <record>\n    <dimEntity.structureId>3J7A</dimEntity.structureId>\n    <dimEntity.chainId>1</dimEntity.chainId>\n    <dimStructure.structureTitle>Cryo-EM structure of the Plasmodium falciparum 80S ribosome bound to the anti-protozoan drug emetine, small subunit</dimStructure.structureTitle>\n    <dimStructure.ndbId>null</dimStructure.ndbId>\n    <dimStructure.resolution>3.2</dimStructure.resolution>\n    <dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>1263059.88</dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>\n    <dimStructure.macromoleculeType>Protein#RNA</dimStructure.macromoleculeType>\n    <dimStructure.residueCount>7121</dimStructure.residueCount>\n    <dimEntity.entityId>27</dimEntity.entityId>\n    <dimEntity.chainLength>133</dimEntity.chainLength>\n    <dimEntity.db_id>Q8I3R6</dimEntity.db_id>\n    <dimEntity.db_name>UniProt</dimEntity.db_name>\n    <dimEntity.molecularWeight>15431.5</dimEntity.molecularWeight>\n    <dimEntity.compound>40S ribosomal protein eS24</dimEntity.compound>\n    <dimEntity.taxonomyId>5833</dimEntity.taxonomyId>\n    <dimEntity.uniprotAcc>Q8I3R6</dimEntity.uniprotAcc>\n    <dimStructure.pubmedId>24913268</dimStructure.pubmedId>\n  </record>\n  <record>\n    <dimEntity.structureId>3J7A</dimEntity.structureId>\n    <dimEntity.chainId>2</dimEntity.chainId>\n    <dimStructure.structureTitle>Cryo-EM structure of the Plasmodium falciparum 80S ribosome bound to the anti-protozoan drug emetine, small subunit</dimStructure.structureTitle>\n    <dimStructure.ndbId>null</dimStructure.ndbId>\n    <dimStructure.resolution>3.2</dimStructure.resolution>\n    <dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>1263059.88</dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>\n    <dimStructure.macromoleculeType>Protein#RNA</dimStructure.macromoleculeType>\n    <dimStructure.residueCount>7121</dimStructure.residueCount>\n    <dimEntity.entityId>28</dimEntity.entityId>\n    <dimEntity.chainLength>105</dimEntity.chainLength>\n    <dimEntity.db_id>Q8ILN8</dimEntity.db_id>\n    <dimEntity.db_name>UniProt</dimEntity.db_name>\n    <dimEntity.molecularWeight>11691.9</dimEntity.molecularWeight>\n    <dimEntity.compound>40S ribosomal protein eS25</dimEntity.compound>\n    <dimEntity.taxonomyId>5833</dimEntity.taxonomyId>\n    <dimEntity.uniprotAcc>Q8ILN8</dimEntity.uniprotAcc>\n    <dimStructure.pubmedId>24913268</dimStructure.pubmedId>\n  </record>\n  <record>\n    <dimEntity.structureId>3J7A</dimEntity.structureId>\n    <dimEntity.chainId>3</dimEntity.chainId>\n    <dimStructure.structureTitle>Cryo-EM structure of the Plasmodium falciparum 80S ribosome bound to the anti-protozoan drug emetine, small subunit</dimStructure.structureTitle>\n    <dimStructure.ndbId>null</dimStructure.ndbId>\n    <dimStructure.resolution>3.2</dimStructure.resolution>\n    <dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>1263059.88</dimStructure.structureMolecularWeight>\n    <dimStructure.macromoleculeType>Protein#RNA"
```

it was downloaded from PDB database using restAPI with this command:

```
baseURL = ('http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/customReport?pdbids=%s&customReportColumns=structureTitle,ndbId,resolution,structureMolecularWeight,macromoleculeType,residueCount,entityId,chainLength,db_id,db_name,molecularWeight,compound,taxonomyId,entityId,uniprotAcc,taxonomyId,pubmedId,pubmedId&service=wsdisplay&ssa=null&primaryOnly=1&service=wsfile' % (_query))
result = requests.get(baseURL)
```

It is currently viewed as a dictionary.

I would like to format the data and convert it to a pandas DataFrame. How do I do this?

I have already tried json

```
jason = json.dumps(pdb_params)
file = StringIO(jason)
```

Unfortunately I am getting errors and probably there is a more effective way of doing this task

Comment: I don't understand. It's Json, XML or CSV?

Comment: It is XML that is put into the dictionary. Then I have tried to convert this dictionary into a string by Json so that it is then readable by Pandas